# Try/except not working with twisted starttls given cert/key mismatch

Tags: python, exception, twisted

So my twisted mail receiver is working nicely. Right up until we try to handle a case where the config is fubarred, and a mismatched cert/key is passed to the certificate options object for the factory.

I have a module, `custom_esmtp.py`, which includes an overload of `ext_STARTLS(self,rest)` which I have modified as follows, to include a try/except:

```
    elif self.ctx and self.canStartTLS:
            try:
                self.sendCode(220, 'Begin TLS negotiation now')
                self.transport.startTLS(self.ctx)
                self.startedTLS = True
            except:
                log.err()
                self.sendCode(550, "Internal server error")
                return
```

When I run the code, having passed a cert and key that do not match, I get the following call stack:

```
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 220, in _dataReceived
    rval = self.protocol.dataReceived(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/protocols/basic.py", line 454, in dataReceived
    self.lineReceived(line)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/mail/smtp.py", line 568, in lineReceived
    return getattr(self, 'state_' + self.mode)(line)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/mail/smtp.py", line 582, in state_COMMAND
    method('')
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "custom_esmtp.py", line 286, in ext_STARTTLS
    self.transport.startTLS(self.ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/_newtls.py", line 179, in startTLS
    startTLS(self, ctx, normal, FileDescriptor)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/_newtls.py", line 139, in startTLS
    tlsFactory = TLSMemoryBIOFactory(contextFactory, client, None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/protocols/tls.py", line 769, in __init__
    contextFactory = _ContextFactoryToConnectionFactory(contextFactory)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/protocols/tls.py", line 648, in __init__
    oldStyleContextFactory.getContext()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/_sslverify.py", line 1429, in getContext
    self._context = self._makeContext()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/_sslverify.py", line 1439, in _makeContext
    ctx.use_privatekey(self.privateKey)
OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('x509 certificate routines', 'X509_check_private_key', 'key values mismatch')]
```

Line 286 of `custom_esmtp.py` is the `self.transport.startTLS(self.ctx)`. I've looked through all the twisted modules listed in the stack, at the quoted lines, and there are no other try/except blocks.... So my understanding is that the error should be passed back up the stack, unhandled, until it reaches my handler in `custom_esmtp.py`? So why is it not getting handled - especially since the only `except` I have is a "catch all"?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this error to be caught, you can do:

```
from OpenSSL import SSL

# ...

try:
    # ...
except SSL.Error:
    # ...
```

Perhaps the syntax changes a bit. I can't check because I don't use this precise package, but the idea is that you have to declare the import path of the exceptions you want to catch.

Comment: But surely, just having a non-specific `except:` handler, this should get picked up already?

Comment: @SteveHall I can recall I had the same problem once and I had to specify the custom exception. Perhaps `except` on its own only takes care of built-in Python exceptions. I have to say I'm not aware of the internal mechanisms at work here.

Comment: Thanks @Jivan - I think that helped - I could see the exception handler was firing, but I was still getting the call stack dumped... oddly, removing the '`log.err()` resolved that! All good now it seems! Thank you!

Comment: @SteveHall thanks for the follow-up. It's quite odd for sure that `log.err()` changes the behaviour, I'll have to check this some day to understand what's happening.

Comment: `log.err()` means "dump the traceback to the log" :)